# Merge a list of single arrays in one array and then sort

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable list of arrays, the list depend of user input. each time the program is called a new set of single arrays is generated.

I been searching for solutions but apparently all solution refer to array of arrays.

Originally the data are from database using:

```
  for ($i = 0; $runrwos= mysql_fetch_assoc($run); $i++) {}
```

after the loop data are inserted in an array:

```
  $data[$i] = array();
```

Using a foreach () {} function data are manipulated with mathematical operations to get the desired outcome. 
The result will output two string of data,

$A is a numeric data

$B has alphabetic value

```
$explodA = explode(" ", $A);
$explodB = explode(" ", $B);
```

Then I combine the result

```
$new = array_combine($explodA, $explodB);
```

when I check result I with

```
var_dump($new);
```

I get the following result:

```
array(1) { [1204]=> string(8) "Home2017" } 
array(1) { [1183]=> string(8) "Home2018" } 
array(1) { [1204]=> string(4) "Stan" } 
array(1) { [1204]=> string(7) "Jun2017" } 
array(1) { [1173]=> string(9) "APRIL2017" } 
.......................................
array(1) { [953]=> string(7) "UNE2018" } 
array(1) { [1171]=> string(6) "MAY201" }
```

I need to sort this data as follow:

```
array(1) { [953]=> string(7) "UNE2018" }
array(1) { [1171]=> string(6) "MAY201" }
array(1) { [1173]=> string(9) "APRIL2017" }
array(1) { [1183]=> string(8) "Home2018" } 
array(1) { [1204]=> string(8) "Home2017" } 
array(1) { [1204]=> string(4) "Stan" } 
array(1) { [1204]=> string(7) "Jun2017" }
```

Can someone direct in the right direction?

I guess the solution is simple but I cannot resolve

Comment: check php sort function

Comment: it work only if the arrays is inside a single array not with a list like mine

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far and where you are having problems?

Comment: Use array_merge http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: foreach ($explodT as $key => $row) {
    $attack[]  = $row;
foreach ($explodG as $keyG => $rowG) {

echo" $row -> $rowG <br/>";

}
}this foreach loop echoe the right result but not sort or built a new single  array

Comment: You need to provide some code for context so people can see where the var_dump output you're showing is coming from. Your current data structure is not apparent from that output.

Comment: $new = array_combine($expEne_deal, $explodT);
$ne=array_flip($new);
for ($x=0; $x <count($ne); $x++)
{
$Line = each($ne);
print "$Line[key] $Line[value] <br>\n";
}
 
This other exmple it also work by giving the right output but either not sort. the output is a var_dump result

Comment: You need to show the code of how you build those arrays and put it in the question. Or what the original data is because there's an easier way I'm sure.

Comment: Originally the data are from database, I have variables that user input, both data are first manipulated with mathematical operations using a foreach loop. The result reflect the database order. My goal is to further order by the result of the calculation. that the reason that the arrays are not from a single array. the original code is quite long and complex. I'm just lost in the last bit of the process.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding more information via comments. Code in comments is very difficult to read, and comments generally aren't intended to be a permanent part of the post.